# Moodle REST API параметры запросов

Tags: python, rest, moodle

Хотел на Python написать несколько скриптов для Moodle, в том числе для перевода студентов в глобальных группах на следующий курс.
Есть документация по API https://moodledev.io/docs/apis, но там нет конкретно параметров запросов именно для REST API.
Конкретно не смог осилить вот такой запрос:

```
https://moodle.ktuniversity.ru/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=4f82c3ddf9c40b47ada58970266c6a3c&wsfunction=core_cohort_add_cohort_members&members=[{"cohortid":184,"userid":2024},{"cohortid":184,"userid":2025}]&moodlewsrestformat=json
```

ответ сервера

```
exception "invalid_parameter_exception"
errorcode "invalidparameter"
message "Обнаружено неверное значение параметра."
```

главные параметры этого запроса

```
members=[{"cohortid":184,"userid":2024},{"cohortid":184,"userid":2025}]
```

Запрос формирую из подстрок, потом конкатенирую и отправляю с помощью requests.

Уперся именно в функцию core_cohort_add_cohort_members,токен рабочий, так как с другими функциями все работает.

С параметрами других функций тоже пришлось возиться, часть нашел здесь, часть от безысходности выпросил у GPT4.

В синатаксисе параметра менял квадратные скобки на круглые и на кавычки - так Клод посоветовал. Ничего не помогло.

Первый раз столкнулся с такой плохой документацией у бородатого и уважаемого проекта.

Comment: Какой метод использовали для запроса `get`или `post`?

Comment: requests.post(url)

Answer (score 0):

Документация по всем включенным функциям Moodle REST API оказалась спрятана внутри самого сайта:

Администрирование > Плагины > Веб-сервисы > Документация API. Кнопка "Напечатать все".

Для меня это было более чем неочевидно, помог Bing Chat,когда я его спросил где взять описание параметров для функций moodle reast api - выдал вышеуказанный путь.

Правильный запрос к Moodle REST API для добавления пользователя с идентификатором 2024 в когорту с идентификатором 184 выглядит так:

```
https://moodle.site.ru/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=4f82c3ddf9c40b47ada58970266c6a3c&wsfunction=core_cohort_add_cohort_members&members[0][cohorttype][type]=id&members[0][cohorttype][value]=184&members[0][usertype][type]=id&members[0][usertype][value]=2024&moodlewsrestformat=json
```